# Prove that a Rational number cubed is a Rational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that when a Rational number is cubed it continues to be a Rational number.

First of all, I tried to find a counterexample, but I did not find any, so it must be true.

I know that any Rational number can be written as a fraction like : $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are whole numbers and $q$ is different than zero. 
So to prove it I did:

Let $n$ be a rational number such that $n$ can be written as $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are whole numbers and $q$ is different than zero,
\begin{align*}
n & = \frac{p}{q}\\
n^3 & = \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^3
\end{align*} 
which is 
$$n^3 = \frac{p^3}{q^3}$$ 
and it still is a Rational number

I am not sure if it is enough to prove that the affirmation is true.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is enough. If you want to be picky, you can add that $q\ne0\implies q^3\ne 0$.

Comment: Maybe add one sentence like "Since $p$ and $q$ are whole numbers (integers, really), then $p^3$ and $q^3$ are also whole numbers." Then $p^3 / q^3$ is a ratio of whole numbers, so it must be rational.

Comment: I'd say the product of two rationals is *defined* as a rational number, so cubes of rationals are as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\frac{p^3}{q^3}=\frac{p*p*p}{q*q*q}$ and we know that the product of any two integers is also an integer, then yes your proof is correct well done.

You should most probably just include the last few steps I've given you.

Comment: I will do that,Thanks everyone